# How to invoke a remote vbs file from local machine?

Tags: vbscript, remote-execution

I have copied a .vbs file to a remote machine which inturn invokes a local application.

Please suggest a way to invoke the remote vbs from the local machine.

I tried with wmi. I need to have UI

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old post, but based on what you're saying, `psexec` from [PsTools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) should do the trick.

You would use it in the following format:

```
psexec \\remote -u remoteuser -p password c:\scripts\script.vbs
```

For full information on `psexec`, see this [TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx.).